# Can we create our own Mobile App Distribution platform (App Store) like Google Play specific to Company?

Tags: android

Our Company has started creating Mobile Apps but they do not want to put it on Android App Store rather they want to create a Company Specific Web Store whose apps can be downloaded by companies Customer and Employees.

Comment: Probably Stackoverflow is not a good place for questions of this kind.

Comment: What is a good place for this guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can create a [Google Play Private Channel](http://googleenterprise.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/a-new-way-to-distribute-your-internal.html) for your organisation.

Or, of course, you can create your own distribution network from scratch. Any file-hosting service can host a `.apk` file.